# Can't change the color of scn file (materials / diffuse.contens) , using ARKit and SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I just made the project: Xcode: File > New > Project > Augmented Reality App.

I want to change the color of the ship.scn to yellow but nothing happened. How can I change the color of the ship.scn ??

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    // here, trying to change the color of the ship.scn
    scene.rootNode.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
    sceneView.scene = scene
}
```

I tried breakpoint and po command to check out what rootNode contains.

```
(lldb) po scene.rootNode.childNodes
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <SCNNode: 0x1c01f8d00 'ship' | 1 child>

(lldb) po scene.rootNode.childNodes.first?.name
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "ship"

(lldb) po scene.rootNode.childNodes.first?.geometry
nil
```

Why geometry is nil?? I can see colored ship.

Comment: scene.rootNode.childNodes.first?.childNodes.first?.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Time for some Swift 101... This line contains [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html):

```
scene.rootNode.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
```

Anytime you see a chain of property accesses / method calls involving *question marks*, the results are, well... *questionable*. In this case, if `rootNode.geometry` is nil, none of the calls after it happen.

So, how to fix the problem? In general, inspect your scene at run time to make sure that the node hierarchy you think you have is what you're actually getting. Use the debugger or some print statements to find out what `rootNode` actually contains, what its child nodes are, what those nodes contain, etc. Or look at the assets you have in the Xcode scene editor, and cross-reference that to figure out what nodes to [search for by name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode#1655236).

In the Xcode project template you're using, the ship geometry isn't on the scene's root node... there are a couple layers of node hierarchy before you get to it. Once you find the right node, setting `diffuse.contents` on its first material will replace the texture map with your color.

Comment: "there are a couple layers of node hierarchy" - thank you very much for the direction!